# Get Parent Attribute in the Current Position with XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have the following data:

```
<books>
    <entry id="8">
        <author name="tony-blair">Tony Blair</author>
    </entry>
    <entry id="9">
        <author name="william-campbell">William Campbell</author>
    </entry>
</books>
```

And use the following template

```
<xsl:template match="books/entry">
    <xsl:value-of select="author"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::books/entry/@id"/>
</xsl:template>
```

I try to use `ancestor::books/entry/@id` but it results only the first id.
How to get the parent entry id while we are in the current position entry?

Comment: The `entry` elements are siblings, they are not in a parent/child relation so it is not clear what you want to achieve when you say "How to get the parent entry id".

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:template match="books/entry">
    <xsl:value-of select="author"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Within a

```
<xsl:template match="books/entry">
```

the current context node is the `entry` element, so you can just use

```
<xsl:value-of select="@id" />
```

You don't need to go up to the `books` element and back down again.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="entry">
    <xsl:value-of select="author"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
</xsl:template>
```

As others have said, you don't need to go up and down the tree.
books/entry is a tiny performance optimisation but it seems you're not there yet, so keep things simple and you're probably not processing massive documents anyway.